# How can I redirect pages in the same tab

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, browser

I have used different code lines for opening webpages in the same tab in IE8 
But they do not seem to work .
Only this piece of code works for me ... that to opens page in new tab

```
window.open("abc.html","_blank");
```

What's the problem  ??

Comment: try window.location.href="abc.html";

Comment: use window.location = "xyz.html"

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
window.location = "xyz.html"
```

Look at the below **Lab:**[labs.codeteam.in/lab/~jRrO2NKaH9d6cD9Ph6s1HTE1bis7MVd](http://www.labs.codeteam.in/lab/~jRrO2NKaH9d6cD9Ph6s1HTE1bis7MVd)

In this case I have used `window.top.location` because the code is executed inside the iframe. In your case you only need to use `window.location`

Comment: I have uploaded on local server ... does this effect

Comment: No it should not. Please see if you are getting any js error on browser console.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code snippet:

```
document.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using asp.net buttons and would like to use target properties to open in the same tab using javascript:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Width="80px" Text="Exit"
 OnClientClick="opennewtab_1();" OnClick="CodeBehind_Click_1" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function opennewtab_1() {
        document.forms[0].target = "_self";
    }
</script>
```